# map with function pointer as key in go

Tags: go

I recently used a map in one of my golang projects, that had function pointers as keys like this:

```
map[*functiontype] somestructtype
```

One of my colleagues said this was a bad idea, so now I am unsure of this being feasible. I initially deemed it ok, because method pointers can be checked for equality and are immutable. Can someone provide some reasoning on that matter?

Complete example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type s struct {
    string
}

type f func() string
func func1() string { return "func 1" }
func func2() string { return "func 2" }

func main() {
    // make two functions and two pointers to them
    f1, f2 := func1, func2
    p1, p2 := (*f)(&f1), (*f)(&f2)

    // make a map of their function pointers
    m := make(map[*f]s)
    m[p1] = s{"struct 1"}
    m[p2] = s{"struct 2"}

    // print out the mapping
    printmapping(m, p1, p2)

    // reverse the pointers and have that printed
    p1, p2 = (*f)(&f2), (*f)(&f1)
    printmapping(m, p1, p2)
}

func printmapping(m map[*f]s, p1, p2 *f) {
    fmt.Println("pointer 1:", m[(*f)(p1)])
    fmt.Println("pointer 2:", m[(*f)(p2)])
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the key type is a *pointer* to a function type (such as `*func()`) then it's totally fine and the semantics are as expected: equal pointers are equal keys.

However, looking up the values in the map may not work out as you may expect: [example](http://play.golang.org/p/Zb66Z_UQ1h). Here `&f` takes the address of the local variable, which is never the same for different invocations of `Add` and `Find`. The following of course could be useful: http://play.golang.org/p/F9jyUxzJhz

---

If it is *not* a pointer, it's a bad idea because it's impossible from Go 1 onwards. According to the language specification ([live demo](http://play.golang.org/p/rsT2eTpm2D)):

> The comparison operators == and != must be fully defined for operands of the key type; thus the key type must not be a function, map, or slice.

`==` and `!=` aren't defined for functions since the problem of comparing functions for equality is undecidable.

Comment: Sorry, I had originally omitted the asterisk before functiontype in my example. So the above (just edited it) would really be ok?

Comment: @PeterHommel There's nothing technically wrong with it, although it is hard to imagine why you would want a pointer to a function. What problem do you think requires this indirection? Note that pointers to functions in Go aren't the same as function pointers in C; they'd be more similar to pointers to function pointers in C.

Comment: I did use them as handler callbacks in a plugin system. Just wanted to attach some data from the outside to every instance of this callback and hence used this type of construct.

Comment: @PeterHommel How would you acquire the pointers to look up the values in the map? Or do you merely use the map for iteration?

Comment: Yes, at the moment just that.

Comment: @PeterHommel Then it should be fine. Note that you cannot do this: http://play.golang.org/p/Zb66Z_UQ1h as `&f` takes the address of the local variable, which is never the same for different invocations of `Add` and `Find`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75791/discussion-between-peter-hommel-and-rightfold).

Answer (score 4):

Your question is too abstract to be meaningful. Give us code for a real example. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

For example, do you mean something like this?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type f func(int) int

type s struct{ i int }

func f1(i int) int { return i }

func f2(i int) int { return i * i }

func main() {
    p1, p2 := f1, f2
    fmt.Println(p1, &p1, p2, &p2)
    m := make(map[*f]s)
    m[(*f)(&p1)] = s{f1(42)}
    m[(*f)(&p2)] = s{f2(42)}
    fmt.Println(m)
    p1, p2 = f2, f1
    fmt.Println(m)
    fmt.Println(p1, &p1, p2, &p2)
}
```

Output:

```
0x20000 0x1040a120 0x20020 0x1040a128
map[0x1040a120:{42} 0x1040a128:{1764}]
map[0x1040a128:{1764} 0x1040a120:{42}]
0x20020 0x1040a120 0x20000 0x1040a128
```

Comment: Not exactly what I did mean, but a good starting point for a complete example. Just rewrote it to make id adhere to my intended question and incorporated it into my question. thx...